# Locking player position in Ursina with an Entity

Tags: python, ursina

- How can I lock the position of my `FirstPersonController` in Ursina
- When my `FirstPersonController` remains standing, another Entity can go through the `FirstPersonController` entity though I used collider. How can I solve that ?

Comment: What do you mean by locking? Making it unable to move around? Please show your code, otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

- What exactly do you mean by "locking" ? You can disable a controller with `your_controller.enabled = False` saying `your_controller` is a `FirstPersonController`.
- A collider is not a wall, it's just something that can interact with `raycasts`. If you want collision, you must shoot a  `raycast`. If it hits something (an `Entity` with a `collider`), check if the `distance()` between the `Entity` and the origin of the `raycast` is below a certain level. Just do something according to the result, like disabling the `Entity`. I'd recommend looking at `FirstPersonController`'s code and globally at [samples](https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/tree/master/samples) on the Ursina repository.